# net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: http: ContentLength=2514 with Body length 0

Tags: go, go-http, backblaze

I am trying to convert a nodejs app to Go. Here I am trying to upload a file to B2. But I am getting  `Post "https://pod-XX.backblaze.com/b2api/v2/b2_upload_file/WERTGVWGTE/cSEREf": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: http: ContentLength=3312 with Body length 0` . Here is my code:

```
// open file
    file, err := os.Open(location)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return "", err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // create sha1 hash of file
    hash := sha1.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return "", err
    }
    sha1Sum := hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))



    // http client
    client := http.Client{}
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", b2.UploadUrl, file)
    contentLength, _ := file.Stat()
    
    req.ContentLength = contentLength.Size()  // without this, its throwing map[code:bad_request message:Missing header: Content-Length status:400]
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", b2.AuthorizationToken)
    req.Header.Set("X-Bz-File-Name", name)
    req.Header.Set("X-Bz-Content-Sha1", sha1Sum)

    res , errr := client.Do(req)
    if errr != nil {
        log.Fatalln(errr)
        return "", errr
    }
```

Just for reference here is the nodejs code that is perfectly working:

```
const file = await fs.readFile(location);
    const sha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(file).digest("hex");
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': auth_token,
            'X-Bz-File-Name': final_name,
            'Content-Type': 'b2/x-auto',
            'X-Bz-Content-Sha1': sha1
        }
    };
    let response = await axios.post(upload_url, file, config);
    return response.data['fileId'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have consumed file here:

```
if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return "", err
    }
```

Use [`func (*File) Seek`](https://pkg.go.dev/os@go1.17.8#File.Seek) or load file to memory.